# How to remove extra spaces & Align drop down list properly using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In this code, i want to remove  remove extra spaces (shown in the image) and also the drop down list is showing in the wrong position(it should be exactly below the list).I just use this single flie.what modifications are needed to resolve this?Please suggest.please let me know for further information.Thanks.
[image]
Html Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Employee Joining Information</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
     margin: 2px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Employee Joining Information Form</h1>

<div class="bs-example"> 
     <form class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label type="text" class="control-label col-xs-2">Employee ID</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eid">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label type="text" class="control-label col-xs-2">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nm">
            </div>
        </div>


 <div class="form-group">
            <label type="text" class="control-label col-xs-2">Designation</label>
        <div class="dropdown" >
  
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose Designation <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
  <li ><a href="#">Manager</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#">Officer</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#">Receptionist</a></li>    
  </ul>
  </div>
  
        </div>
        
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not using Bootstrap's grid system properly. You should read up on containers, rows, and columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was your dropdown needed to be wrapped inside `<div class="col-xs-5"></div>`

```css
.bs-example{
 margin: 2px;
}
label.control-label.col-xs-2 {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Employee Joining Information</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>Employee Joining Information Form</h1>

<div class="bs-example"> 
     <form class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label type="text" class="control-label col-xs-2">Employee ID</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eid">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label type="text" class="control-label col-xs-2">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nm">
            </div>
        </div>


 <div class="form-group">
            <label type="text" class="control-label col-xs-2">Designation</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
              <div class="dropdown" >
  
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose Designation <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
  <li ><a href="#">Manager</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#">Officer</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#">Receptionist</a></li>    
  </ul>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks it works.but how to remove  this extra spaces

Comment: If your goal is to left align the text, go for `text-align: left;`. I updated my answer with the change.  Bootstrap divides the site up in 2/12th of the width, and 5/12th of the width in your code, therefore there will be some spacing on larger resolution, and less spacing on lower resolution.

Comment: @user5005768: You should know, the bigger screen resolution you have, the more spacing it would be. Thats how Bootstrap works. Max width is 1200px or something like that, the rest will become equal padding on each side.